# Не получается вывести максимумы из массива

Tags: java

```
public class MaxAndMin {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        int[] age = new int[4];
        int i;

        for(i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            age[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
        }

        Arrays.sort(age, Collections.reverseOrder());

        System.out.println(age[0] + " " + age[1]);
    }
}
```

В строке Arrays.sort(age, Collections.reverseOrder()); - ругается на age

Required type:T[]

Provided:int[]

reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) T exist so that int[] conforms to T[]

Idea предлагает решить проблему таким образом:

Arrays.sort(new int[][]{age}, Collections.reverseOrder());

но тогда сортировка не срабатывает и выводится просто первый элемент массива

Comment: А какой смысл в том, что бы делать реверс массива? Если тебе нужно вывести 2 максимальных числа, то сделай просто Arrays.sort, а потом выводи age[age.length - 1] и age[age.length - 2]

Comment: А зачем вообще в этой задаче сортировка? вот они программисты 21 века.... а главное 2 ответа и оба с сортировкой, люди что с вами?

Comment: Обратная? или вообще сортировка?

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков а как еще можно найти максимальный элемент не проходя по нему линейно?) Вопрос был не как лучше сделать, а как сделать так, чтобы это заработало :)

Comment: @pimmpo А у нас сортировка в общем случае стала O(n) ? Насколько мне память не изменяет O(n) можно добиться только в некоторых экзотических случаях. Против линейного прохода - ничего против не имею, и даже за =)
**автору**: сортировка вообще, сортировка в этой задачи - от лени и нежелания понимать алгоритмы

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков в данной реализации использует сортировка слиянием, если я не ошибаюсь в среднем она будет выдавать n log n, что быстрее линейного прохода, на массиве из 4 элементов оно может и хуже, но в перспективе то :)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков  а программисты из 20 века не читают задание? Там же нужно 2 максимальных элемента, а не один. И проще и лаконичней всего это сделать сортировкой. А если понадобится больше чем 2 это легко переделать. А искать несколько максимальных элементов используя линейные проходы такая себе идея, особенно на таком маленьком количестве данных.

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon Читают, и за один линейный проход массива - никакой проблемы выбрать два больших значения(если не знаете как - это не повод заявлять что я не читал условия задачи).

Comment: @МаксимАлексеенко попробуйте обычным перебором найти сначало максимальное число, как только это получится - думаю труда не составит доработать алгоритм чтобы находить 2 числа

Comment: Банальщина решается через 2 переменные, классическим способом, через перебор и запись в переменную большего числа, а после просто проверяется 2 переменная, что она больше всех и меньше предыдущего записанного в первой переменной.

Comment: @And можете продемонстрировать? очень интересно как

Comment: @And, твой алгоритм сработает только в том случае, если максимальные числа различны. Проще действительно сделать сортировку и не париться по мелочам. Если конечно функция не является критичной по времени. Преждевременная оптимизация -- корень всех зол.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков ок бумер. Вы, я смотрю, из того типа людей, которые не хотят принимать ничего нового, а вместо этого пишите комментарии вроде "Вот в наше время программисты знали алгоритмы, а сейчас тупая молодежь обленилась". Интересно, чтобы найти одно максимальное число, вы тоже будете перебирать весь массив? На сколько надо не ценить свое время, чтобы каждый раз пытаться реализовать то, что уже давно реализовано в лучшем виде и доступно в виде удобных методов? Ну, а вы и дальше можете считать свои байтики.

Comment: @NarasuOo да, я из тих кто смотрит на сложность алгоритмов перед их выбором, сортировка - всегда, кроме крайне редких случаев, сложнее(ресурсозатратней) чем простой проход по массиву, и да я считаю что учится нужно делать правильно, делать неправильно(потому что это проще) - человек всегда сможет, если будет знать об этом.

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков возмущаться на сортировку из 4 элементов это очень странное поведение, особенно с использованием выражений "вот они программисты 21 века", сразу хочется сказать ок бумер :). Можно уж тогда возмущаться, что это не на ассемблере написано. "если не знаете как - это не повод заявлять что я не читал условия задачи" да, это такой сложный алгоритм для программистов 21 века, а ещё я не верю в математику и у меня 2+2=5, как и у всех программистов 21 века

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков признаю линейно пройти будет быстрее, посмотрел среднее время на сортировку(Arrays.sort) n log n, не уверен на счет удобности поиска сразу нескольких элементов и да высказывание "вот они программисты 21 века" не совсем корректно с моей точки зрения

Comment: @pimmpo я рад что смог донести эту мысль. по поводу "программистов 21 века"  - это просто общая тенденция, писать неоптимальный код и даже не задумываться какие проблемы он вызовет. Всётаки поколение постарше(опытом, не возрастом) - видит разницу, и использует то что подходит под ситуацию, а не то что проще написать.... А в учебных примерах, мое личное мнение, не место таким алгоритмам, точнее место, но для демонстрации их прожорливости...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что, у вас вызвалась реализация [public static  void sort(T[] a, Comparator c)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(T[],%20java.util.Comparator)), а она требует массив объектов (генерики).

Вам бы подошла [public static void sort(int[] a)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])), но для массивов с простыми типами не предусмотрена функция компаратора.

Попробуйте так:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

Integer[] age = new Integer[4];
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    age[i] = Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine());
}

Arrays.sort(age, Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println(age[0] + " " + age[1]);
```

---

Возможно, удобнее будет через списки работать:

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

List<Integer> age = new ArrayList<>();

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    age.add(Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()));
}

age.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

System.out.println(age.get(0) + " " + age.get(1));
```

Comment: Arrays.sort может работать с примитивными данными

Comment: @pimmpo, а я не писал что не может, прочтите внимательнее начало ответа :) И, кст, наши ответы повторяются, хотя по времени почти одновременно выложили ответы (мой ответ на 12 секунд раньше), но мне при этом минус поставили, забавно :)

Answer (score 2):

Проблем в том, что Collections.reverseOrder() - это обобщенный метод, такие методы не умеют работать с примитивными типами данных[int, double, char]. Для них существует классы обёртки как у вас в коде Integer, Double и другие. Как вариант решения объявите свой массив с классом Integer - пример ниже.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int size = 4;
    Random random = new Random();
    Integer[] arr = new Integer[size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = random.nextInt();
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n");
    Arrays.sort(arr, Collections.reverseOrder());

    for(int obj: arr) {
        System.out.println(obj);
    }
}
```